# How to forbid recursive copy in SVN?

Tags: svn, copy

I have a repository with a following top-level structure:

```
/trunk/a
/trunk/b
/branches/b1
/branches/b2
/extra_dir
```

My colleagues don't sleep well and do often make mistakes like:

```
svn cp /trunk /trunk/a/branches/b3
```

As a result we have `/trunk/a` inside itself at some depth. Since `/trunk/a` size is 1Tb, I want to prevent this situation in any possible way, including transitive copy attempts like:

```
svn cp /trunk /branches/b4/z/y/x
svn cp /branches/b4/z/y /trunk/a/z/y
```

I tried to write a hook that traverses files inside all the `cp` commits, but it works for too long, since the repository contains more than ~1M files/directories, and hook doesn't track transitive copies.

Is there an efficient way to forbid recursive copies of `/trunk/a`?